# Node Express code working with latest version of jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

Is there a node express code that works with the latest version of jQuery-File-Upload? All the ones I could find were quite old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [jquery-file-upload-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-file-upload-middleware#star) , [blueimp-file-upload-expressjse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs) and on this [tutorial](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/uploading-files-made-fun) , explaning how to use the last package.

I've used it (the latter), and it works like a charm.